# JanusGraph get vertex by id/key

Tags: janusgraph

I did a few scattered imports from GraphSON formatted files. As a result now when I execute the command `g.V()`, I receive the following results:

```
==>v[{@type=g:Int32, @value=1}]
==>v[0]
==>v[1]
==>v[{@type=g:Int32, @value=3}]
==>v[{@type=g:Int32, @value=2}]
==>v[{@type=g:Int32, @value=4}]
==>v[1.1.1.6]
```

My file that produces the vertex  - 1.1.1.6 is looking like that:

```
{"id":"1.1.1.6","label":"test","outE":{"accelerate":[{"id":0,"inV":"00561"}, {"id":1,"inV":"00640"}]}}
```

The problem is that I can't get vertex 1.1.1.6. So how can I query the DB by key/id?

I surely can make a property iid, that duplicates the data, create an index on this property and then search with `g.V().has('iid', '1.1.1.6')` but is this the right way?

Comment: are you able to share the graphson file? can you update the question with the command you used to load the file?

Answer (score 2):

You look up a vertex by id by using the V() method directly:

```
g.V('1.1.1.6')
```